# Limits of an integrable function over increasing sequence of sets

Tags: integration, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(E_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be an increasing sequence of sets such that $\bigcup_{n \geq 1} E_n = \Omega$. Then for every integrable function $f$ we have $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{E_n} f d\mu = \int_{\Omega} f d\mu.$$

I think we have to start by showing that the result is true for a simple function. But I don't know how to complete the proof.

Comment: Have you allready proved the dominated convergence theorem? If yes, this is an easy application of it.

Comment: Start by proving it for nonnegative functions. In that case define $f_{n}$ as $f\times 1_{E_{n}}$ and notice that $f_{n}\uparrow f$.

Comment: Every integrable function on which domain?

Comment: @zhw.: note that the OP has not been around for four and half years.

Comment: @MartinArgerami You're right. I guess I'll never know which domain ...

Answer (score 1):

For a simple function, the result relies on the fact that if $S$ is measurable, then $\mu(S\cap E_n)\to \mu(S)$. Writing $f:=\max\{f,0\}+(f-\max\{0,f\})$, we can assume that $f$ is non negative. Then we use the definition of Lebesgue integral of non-negative functions, that is, 
$$\int g\mathrm d\mu=\sup\left\{\int s\mathrm d\mu, s\mbox{ simple, }0\leqslant s\leqslant g\right\}.$$
We fix a positive $\varepsilon$ and we take $s$ simple such that $\int (f-s)\mathrm d\mu\lt \varepsilon$. We have 
$$\left|\int_{E_n}f\mathrm d\mu-\int f\mathrm d\mu\right|\leqslant \left|\int_{E_n}s\mathrm d\mu-\int s\mathrm d\mu\right|+\left|\int_{E_n}(f-s)\mathrm d\mu-\int (f-s)\mathrm d\mu\right|\leqslant\left|\int_{E_n}s\mathrm d\mu-\int s\mathrm d\mu\right|+2\varepsilon.$$